# NSAlert.runModal() is failing with Exception "[NSAlert runModal] may only be invoked from the main thread. Behavior on other threads is undefined."

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, pyobjc

I am writing a MACOS application using Pyobjc and Python 3. I am trying to show an alert with ok and cancel button. The code below is in a daemon thread (unfortunately). The runModal() function is throwing below exception

"[NSAlert runModal] may only be invoked from the main thread. Behavior on other threads is undefined."

My code is below

```
    from AppKit import NSAlert, NSInformationalAlertStyle, NSApp

    alert = NSAlert.alloc().init()
    alert.setMessageText_(text)
    alert.setInformativeText_(title)
    alert.setAlertStyle_(NSInformationalAlertStyle)
    for button in title_buttons:
        alert.addButtonWithTitle_(button)
    NSApp.activateIgnoringOtherApps_(True)
    return alert.runModal() # This line throws exception.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I understand that this is happening because it is being invoked not from the main thread but a separate thread. But that is something, because of the business-logic and I can't change that. The above code works fine, when run from a test.py file, which kind of confirms my understanding of the issue. I tried with DispatchQueue etc but couldn't make it work.

Comment: Pretty much anything related to the UI has to be run from the main thread.  You might try using a separate helper process that can.

Comment: Thanks red_menace, could you please share some example code on how this can be achieved. So basically the business logic is running on a separate/non-main thread. I need to show a modal dialog from that thread and depending upon the users input, the flow will proceed.